# Parsing text into an object in MVC with missing data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, model-binding

I am getting some post data from an HTML form. The data that comes up is used to build a `TextualReport` object. I want to parse the various pieces of form data that come up and populate those parts of my model.

The reason i am not using a model binder is this is a fairly complex object and indices of my lists can be missing (start at 2, skip 3 etc..). I am starting with an existing object, and only replacing the properties that came up in the post.

I have the following object called `TextualReport`.

```
public class TextualReport {

    public IList<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public IList<string> MiscInputs { get; set; }

    public TextualReport(){
        Sections = new List<Section>();
        MiscInputs = new List<string>();
    }
}

public class Section{
    public Section(){
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Blocks = new List<Block>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public IList<Block> Blocks { get; set; }
}

public class Block{
    public Block(){
        PreGraphText = new List<string>();
        PreGraphInput = new List<string>();
        Graphs = new List<Graph>();
        PostGraphText = new List<string>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public IList<string> PreGraphText { get; set; }
    public IList<Graph> Graphs { get; set; }
    public IList<string> PostGraphText { get; set; }
    public IList<string> PreGraphInput { get; set; }
}

public class Graph{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

From my HTML/Razor form, I get a sequence of text strings like the following:

```
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[0].Graphs[0].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[0].Graphs[1].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[0].Graphs[2].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[0].PreGraphInput[0]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[0].PreGraphInput[1]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[1].Graphs[0].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[1].PreGraphInput[0]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[1].PreGraphInput[1]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[2].Graphs[0].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[2].Graphs[1].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[2].PreGraphInput[0]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[2].PreGraphInput[1]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[3].Graphs[0].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[3].PreGraphInput[0]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[3].PreGraphInput[1]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[4].Graphs[0].Caption=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[4].PreGraphInput[0]=
TextualReport.Sections[1].Blocks[4].PreGraphInput[1]=
```

What would be the best approach to populate my existing data with the various pieces that came up in the form post? I get the model from the database, then update based on the new data.

Comment: can you add the code for your view? Most importantly your Razor/HTML controls. It's good to see which controls you use.